# Getting filtered data from a tableView in appcelerator

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a search bar attached to a tableView

```
searchBar = Ti.UI.createSearchBar({
    value : null,
});

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    filterAttribute: 'filterCriteria',
    search = searchBar
});


var tbl_data = [
   {title:'Row 12', filterCriteria : 'Row 12'},
   {title:'Row 2', filterCriteria : 'Row 2'},
   {title:'Row 3', filterCriteria : 'Row 3'}
];

table.setData(tbl_data);
```

When I input information into the bar for example "2", the rows are filtered according to the value I input within the search box; in the case of filter "2" the results given would be [{title:'Row 12'}, {title:'Row 2'}]

I can access all data/rows within the table by using

```
table.data[0].rows;
```

How am I able to access the filtered rows within the table?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-property-filterAttribute the `filterAttribute` define the property of the `TableViewRow` to be used. So, you must add this property on your `TableViewRow` like this :

```
var tbl_data = [
  {title:'Row 12', filterCriteria : 'Row 12'},
  {title:'Row 2', filterCriteria : 'Row 2'},
  {title:'Row 3', filterCriteria : 'Row 3'}
];
```

Then, if you want access to the filtered row, you can add the click event on your `TableView` :

```
table.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  Ti.API.log(' e.row ' + JSON.stringify(e.row)); //the clicked row
});
```

Comment: I forgot to add in my original description "filterCreteria", unfortunaly what you described doesn't answer my question properly as it only accesses a single row. I desire to be able to access all rows that satisfy the filter.